# Google spreadsheets: Make tools menu unavailable to editors

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-sheets-api

My question:
Is it possible to make the Tools Menu in google spreadsheets unavailable for editors?
My users must modify some columns in a file so they must be editors; but they should not use commands from menu (in particular Tools menu).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is *no*.

**Long answer :** there is no way to modify the spreadsheet toolbar other than adding a custom menu.